# Search text with Content.Find object and recover the text found

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

I want to search an entire MSWord document for a text with wildcards and recover the strings found.

something like that:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveDocument.Contentsdf
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With c.Find
        .Text = "start[abcde]end"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False '
    End With

    c.Find.Execute
    While c.Find.Found
        Debug.Print c.Find.TextFound
        c.Find.Execute
    Wend
End Sub
```

but the method `c.Find.TextFound` does not exists. Is there any way to recover the text without recurring to `Selection.Text`?

Comment: Do you wan to search for `*abcde*` or `start*end`?

Comment: i want to search string that begins with "start", ends with "end" and contain any of "a","b", "c","d", "e" letters in the middle.

Comment: Can you give an example? `start[a]end` or `start[asd]end` or `startaend` or `startasdend`

Comment: Here is an example: the body of the document is : "startAend startEend startFend startQend ...<a lot of startALetterend>... startWend startAend". I want to search some of them (those with letters "A", "B", "C", "D" and "E" in the middle) and recover the strings found in order to manipulate them later.

Comment: I know that this can be done using Find.Text = "start[abcde]end" and I can recover the text with Selection.Text iterating over every hit found. But I am modifying a code written in perl by other people that uses VBA through WIN32::OLE and I do not have access to Word.Selection object (I need to modify a lot of code to do this), so I want to know if there is any way to recover the text found from the Find object.

Comment: Had stepped out for some time... posted the code below.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String

    StartWord = "Start": EndWord = "End"

    Set c = ActiveDocument.Content
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With c.Find
        .Text = StartWord & "*" & EndWord
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False '
    End With

    c.Find.Execute
    While c.Find.Found
        Debug.Print c.Text
        '~~> I am assuming that the start word and the end word will only
        '~~> be in the start and end respectively and not in the middle
        Debug.Print Replace(Replace(c.Text, StartWord, ""), EndWord, "")
        c.Find.Execute
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a way to print a certain number of pages as long as it has a certain word.

Basically I have 3 files and I have to print them and organize them by shifts. Each of them as the words Shift 1 2 and 3 on them. I managed to put them all printing at once but I want to print Shift 1 from the first file, shift 2 from the second file, and so on till shift 3 of file 5. I just need a macro code that will search the word "shift 1" in the file and print only the pages that contain that word. Then is basically applying the same code to all the files, changing 1 to 2 and to 3.

Correct me if I'm wrong.