# Find / Replace text using string found within Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been trying to modify the brilliant example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480421/search-text-with-content-find-object-in-word-with-vba-and-recover-the-text-found?rq=1) with little success. Within the MSWord document, I need to be able to find text like `<<TEST>>` and recover the string found between `<<` and `>>` which would return `TEST`. Ultimately I intend to use this to look up a value against `TEST` and return a string to be replaced within the Word document. ie. `<<TEST>>` becomes `FRED` for example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String, TheWord As String

    StartWord = "<<": EndWord = ">>"

    Set c = ActiveDocument.Content
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With c.Find
        .Text = "[\<]{2}*[\>]{2}"
        '.Replacement.Text = TheWord
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    c.Find.Execute
    While c.Find.Found
        Debug.Print c.Text
        TheWord = Replace(Replace(c.Text, StartWord, ""), EndWord, "")
        Debug.Print TheWord
        c.Find.Replacement.Text = TheWord
        ' Future something here to lookup value based on 'TheWord'
        c.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    Wend
End Sub
```

At the moment, I'm just trying to replace those words like `<<TEST>>` that are found with the string found within. Although it will find and replace the first instance of the text matching the pattern, it doesn't find others like the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480421/search-text-with-content-find-object-in-word-with-vba-and-recover-the-text-found?rq=1) will.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if sometimes it is not recommended to use `Selection` within your code I prefer to use it when running `find >> replace` actions.

In the following code you will find two solutions- **1st** is to replace text with one inside `<<` `>>` brackets, **2nd** is to replace with any text. Do not run both at once, comment one to run the other.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String, TheWord As String

    StartWord = "<<": EndWord = ">>"

    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[\<]{2}(*)[\>]{2}"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    'DO NOT RUN BOTH OPTIONS TOGETHER, CHOOSE ONE

    'OPTION 1. replace to inside text
    'Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    'OPTION 2. replace to any text, here- inside text found with replace function
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute

        Debug.Print Selection.Text
        TheWord = Replace(Replace(Selection.Text, StartWord, ""), EndWord, "")
        Debug.Print TheWord
        Selection.Text = TheWord
        Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd

    Loop
End Sub
```